# Fastest Cython implementation depends on computer?

Tags: numpy, optimization, cython, baduk

I am converting a python script to cython and optimizing it for more speed. Right now i have 2 versions, on my desktop V2 is twice as fast as V1 unfortunately on my laptop V1 is twice as fast as V2 and i am unable to find out why there is such a big difference.
Both computers use:
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Python 2.7.12
- Cython 0.25.2
- Numpy  1.12.1
Desktop:
- Intel® Core™ i3-4370 CPU @ 3.80GHz × 4 64bit. 16GB RAM
Laptop:
- Intel® Core™ i5-3210 CPU @ 2.5GHz × 2 64bit. 8GB RAM

**V1** - you can find the full code [here](https://github.com/MaMiFreak/RocAlphaGo/tree/Cython_V1/AlphaGo). the only changes made are renaming `go.py`, `preprocessing.py` to `go.pyx`, `preprocessing.pyx` and using
`import pyximport; pyximport.install()`  to compile them. you can run `test.py`. This version is using a 2d numpy array `board` to store data in `go.pyx` and  list comprehension in the `get_board` function in `preprocessing.pyx` to process data. during the test no function is called from `go.py` only the numpy array `board` is used

**V2** - you can find the full code [here](https://github.com/MaMiFreak/RocAlphaGo/blob/Cython_V2/AlphaGo). quite some stuff has changed, below you can find a list with everything affecting this test case. Be aware, all function and variable declarations have to be in `go.pxd`. you can run `test.py` using this command: `python test.py build_ext --inplace`
the 2d numpy array is replaced by:

```
cdef char board[ 362 ]
```

and the function `get_board_feature` in `go.pyx` replaces numpy list comprehension:

```
cdef char get_board_feature( self, short location ):
    # return correct board feature value
    # 0 active player stone
    # 1 opponent stone
    # 2 empty location

    cdef char value = self.board[ location ]

    if value == EMPTY:
        return 2

    if value == self.player_current:
        return 0

    return 1
```

`get_board` function in `preprocessing.pyx` is replaced with a function that loops over the array and calls `get_board_feature` in `go.pyx` for every location

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef int get_board(self, GameState state, np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] tensor, int offSet ):
    """A feature encoding WHITE BLACK and EMPTY on separate planes, but plane 0
       always refers to the current player and plane 1 to the opponent
    """

    cdef short location

    for location in range( 0, state.size * state.size ):

        tensor[ offSet + state.get_board_feature( location ), location ] = 1

    return offSet + 3
```

Please let me know if i should include any other information or run certain tests.

**cmp, diff test**
the V2 `go.c` and `preprocessing.c` files are identical.
V1 does not generate a `.c` file to compare

**update compared `.so` files**
the V2 `go.so` files are different:

```
goD.so goL.so differ: byte 473, line 1
```

the `preprocessing.so` files are identical, not sure what to think of that..

Comment: My feeling is that this is too much code for me to dig into (and I suspect other people will feel the same). General advice is: I'd start by trying to profile it (on both systems) and see if you can identify which functions show the big differences in the profiled data. If you can get that down then you could probably construct a smaller test-case just using the function that shows the main difference.

Comment: The second thing I'd include in the question is details of the CPUs in the two systems. Is one 32 bit and the other 64 bit for example - I could imagine that could make a big difference in terms of preferred data types?

Comment: Well only the things i mention are being used but i see your point and will create a clean version for readability. Good point about the CPUs i will add that information

Comment: I'd also double check if the compiled modules produced are identical (`diff` or `cmp`). I imagine they should be, but if not then that could be something to look at.

Comment: i removed all unused code so code should readable, only have to add an explanation on the `go.py` from V1 as only the numpy array is used.

Comment: okay, never done that will check how i can do so

Comment: I actually meant "are the binary .so files the same?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are two different machines and behave differently. There's a reason why processor reviews use large benchmark suites. It could be said that the desktop CPU performs better on average, but execution times between two small but non-trivial pieces of codes does not 'have' to favor the desktop CPU. And differences  execution times definitely do not have to follow any linear relationship. The performance is always dependant on a huge amount of factors. Possible explanations include but are not limited to the smaller L1 and L2 caches on the desktop and the change in vector instruction sets from AVX to AVX2 between the Ivy Bridge laptop and the Haswell desktop.

Generally it's a good idea to concentrate on using good algorithms and to identify and remove bottlenecks when optimizing performance. Trying to stare at benchmarks between different machines will probably only cause a headache.

Comment: Thanks! This crossed my mind but the code in question is a simple array lookup, comparison and setting a value in a different array and it seems rather extreme to get a 2X speed difference in favor of V1 or V2 depending on   what computer one uses.

Comment: What kind of speeds are we talking about?